# LINQ XML Document

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a simple XML Document like this

```
<Pictures>
  <Picture>
    <Source>1</Source>
    <Title>One</Title>
  </Picture>
  <Picture>
   <Source>2</Source>
   <Title>Two</Title>
  </Picture>
<Pictures>
```

Im trying to grab the values of 1 and 2. Heres what Im trying.

```
foreach (XmlNode mynode in doc.ChildNodes)
      {
        var source = mynode.SelectSingleNode("//Source").InnerText;
        var title = mynode.SelectSingleNode("//Title").InnerText;
      }
```

The problem is this returns the value of 1 twice, and the value of One twice, instead of 1 and 2, im assuming because the "//" means the topmose match. I guess my twofold question is...

How would I do this?
How would I do this in Linq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("path");

var pictures = xDoc.Root
           .Elements("Picture")
           .Select(x => new 
                        {  
                            source = (string)x.Element("Source"),
                            title = (string)x.Element("Title")
                        }).ToList();
```

Comment: I just cant wrap my head around LINQ. That is so beautiful. Where would you suggest to learn how to use LINQ correctly.

Comment: @CalvinSmith i would suggest reading Jon Skeet's edulinq series. where he implements LINQ to objects. https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/02/23/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-45-conclusion-and-list-of-posts.aspx

Comment: @rezomegreldize But the Linq to XML stuff is not really obvious even if you are familiar with Linq.